# How to return enum value by 2 parameters in java

Tags: java, enums

I have such enum class in java

```
    public enum MockTypes
    {
        // Atlantis mocks
        ATLANTIS_VERIFY("ATLANTIS", "verify"),
        ATLANTIS_CREATE_RECORD("ATLANTIS", "createRecord"),

    ...

        private String m_adaptor;

        private String m_step;

private MockTypes( String adaptor, String step)
    {
        m_adaptor = adaptor;
        m_step = step;
    }

             public String getAdaptor()
        {
            return m_adaptor;
        }

        public String getStep()
        {
            return m_step;
        }
```

I have to implement method that returns enum value by adaptor and step parameter.

```
public MockTypes getMockTypeByName(String adaptor, String step)
```

but I have no idea how. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public MockTypes getMockTypeByName(String adaptor, String step)
{
    for(MockTypes m : MockTypes.values())
    {
        if(m.getAdaptor().equals(adaptor) && 
           m.getStep().equals(step)) return m;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why `equalsIgnoreCase`?  (It really, really shouldn't be your default.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman The OP can use `equals()` instead if he wants, it's up to him.

Comment: Yes, but...for you to suggest it is weird.  `equals` is the _default_, no?  And nothing the OP's mentioned implies that casing is a problem?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I edited my answer as you suggested, and you are right the OP didn't mention anything about case-sensitive :)

Comment: Fun fact, by the way: Calling `values()` for an enum type rebuilds the whole array every time, but iterating over `EnumSet.allOf(MockTypes.class)` only does O(1) work.

Comment: It works. A was thinking about it, but it can take a time if enum is big. I'm trying to find solution like valueOf(....) w/o iteration over enum values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "constant-time" solution that doesn't involve looking up values, your best option is to initialize a constant `Map` in a static block in the `MockType` class.

If you're up for using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), it'll actually be relatively pleasant:

```
public enum MockType {
  ...

  private static final ImmutableTable<String, String, MockType> LOOKUP_TABLE;

  static {
    ImmutableTable.Builder<String, String, MockType> builder =
      ImmutableTable.builder();
    for (MockType mockType : MockType.values()) {
      builder.put(mockType.getAdaptor(), mockType.getStep(), mockType);
    }
    LOOKUP_TABLE = builder.build();
  }

  public static MockType getMockType(String adaptor, String step) {
    return LOOKUP_TABLE.get(adaptor, step);
  }
}
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

The alternative is going to be relatively similar -- construct a `Map<String, Map<String, LookupType>>` in a static block, and do lookups from there -- though it's going to require somewhat more work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum`'s `values()` method to obtain a list of all the defined values. You can then loop through this list and find the values you're interested in that match the ones sent as parameters to the method.

Comment: I need only one value that matches two parameters

Comment: @ConstantineGladky, you can loop through what `values()` returns to find the value you're looking for. `values()` will return a list of all possible `MockTypes`. You could also make a `Map`, caching these values, if the loop performance is a concern.